# Python finding the degree of a given vertex in a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, graph-theory

i need to implement a function named degree that has parameters graph and vertex, that finds the degree of a given vertex where the length of the vertex is len<(Graph),
one graph im using to test this function is

```
 simple_graph = [[0,1,1,1],
                [1,0,1,0],
                [1,1,0,0],
                [1,0,0,0]]
```

i need to check if a path from the given vertices to other exists and then increment the degree by one
here is my code so far but its not working

```
def degree(Graph, vertex):
    degree = 0
    for i in range(graph.vertex): 
        if graph[ver][i] == 1: 
        degree += 1
    return degree
```

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: ver needs to be changed vertex.

Comment: can't you just `return sum(graph[vertex])`

Comment: @Boris wow that worked,i thought ineeded to iterate through the object

Comment: @asyl in the future, you'll get more answers faster if you include the output you expect. I had to google what the degree of a vertex was, and a lot of people don't want to waste time trying to understand your question because they might end up just realizing they can't answer it.